# Save requestVars to database model in Silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm getting some values from a form via getRequest() - the values come through fine, but just trying to figure out how to save this into the database - the Model is setup and has the same names as the form is posting - I'm trying this, but it's not working so obviously I have to convert the request array first??:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$vars = $request->requestVars();

//Create submission object
$submission = new Submission();     
$vars->saveInto($submission);
$submission->write();
```

Comment: Can you please share the code for `Submission`? The `saveInto` method is mainly for Form instances - do you have a Form instance here you can use instead to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$request->requestVars()` will return an array... and you're using the saveInto() method on what's returned in $vars (an array) and that's not correct...

You should have something like `$form->saveInto($submission)`;

So here's a very short example of how would this work with a simple Newsletter form and a Submission data object.

Here you have a page controller, where the form is defined. When the user hits the form's submit button (Subscribe in this case), the form data will be processed in the `doSubmitNewsletterForm()` method, where you basically save the submitted data into a new `Submission` data object.

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

    private static $allowed_actions = array (
        'NewsletterForm'
    );

    public function NewsletterForm() {
        // Form Fields
        $fields = FieldList::create(
          $firstname = TextField::create('Firsname', 'First Name'),
          $lastname = TextField::create('Lastname', 'Last Name'),
          $email = EmailField::create('Email', 'Email Address')
        );

        // Actions
        $submit = FormAction::create('doSubmitNewsletterForm', 'Subscribe');
        $actions = FieldList::create($submit);

        // Validators
        $validator = RequiredFields::create(array('Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Email'));

        // Form
        $form = Form::create($this, 'NewsletterForm', $fields, $actions);

        return $form;
    }


    /**
     * Process the form data
     */
    public function doSubmitNewsletterForm($data, Form $form) {
      $submission = new Submission();

      $form->saveInto($submission);

      $submission->write();
    }
}
```

and here's the Submission data object:

```
class Submission extends DataObject {

  private static $db = array(
    'Firstname'   =>  'Varchar(100)',
    'Lastname'    =>  'Varchar(100)',
    'Email'       =>  'Varchar(100)',
  );

  public static getCMSFields() {
    // bla bla bla
  }

  // bla bla bla - other methods

}
```

**That's it!!!**

Now if you're not using a form, all you can do is something like this:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$vars = $request->requestVars();

$sumbission = new Submission();
$submission->Firstname = $vars['Firstname'];
$submission->Lastname = $vars['Lastname'];
$submission->Email = $vars['Email'];
$submission->write();
```

... or you could try this (never used it, so I'm not sure it will work):

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$vars = $request->requestVars();

$submission = new Submission();
$submission->update($vars);
$submission->write();
```

... not sure if the update() method will work if the Submission data object is not saved yet, so if the above is not working, try this:

```
$submission = new Submission();
$submission->write();
$submission->update($vars);
$submission->write();
```

All in all, have a look on the `update()` method in the DataObject class (DataObject.php file) and you'll see what it does (you'll see that the only parameter it expects it's an array of key/value pairs, so I guess it should work like I mentioned above:

```
/**
 * Update a number of fields on this object, given a map of the desired changes.
 *
 * The field names can be simple names, or you can use a dot syntax to access $has_one relations.
 * For example, array("Author.FirstName" => "Jim") will set $this->Author()->FirstName to "Jim".
 *
 * update() doesn't write the main object, but if you use the dot syntax, it will write()
 * the related objects that it alters.
 *
 * @param array $data A map of field name to data values to update.
 * @return DataObject $this
 */
public function update($data) {
  foreach($data as $k => $v) {
    // some other core Silverstrip code
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - for various reasons I can't just save the form object into  the db using $form->saveInto - so I'll have to do each field individually or try playing around with update()- lucky it's only a short form !